# How to transform traditional Chinese string into simplified Chinese string in Mathematica?

Tags: character-encoding, linguistics

There are two type of written Characters in Chinese: traditional Chinese and simplified Chinese. Is there a way to transform traditional Chinese string into simplified Chinese string in Mathematica? For example, transform "簡體" into “简体”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Transliterate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transliterate.html) does that (from 2015). I used free form syntax to find the entities. As an example, I typed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> then wrote "traditional chinese" to find the related entity. The code is then :

```
Transliterate["簡體", 
 Entity["WritingScript", "TraditionalChinese::bjw79"] -> 
  Entity["WritingScript", "SimplifiedChinese::zzc7y"]]
```

`"简体"`

Comment: Thank you so much!